# Kronecker delta - can I change one index and not another one in the same expression?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, simple question about index notation. If I have this:-

$$
\delta^\mu_\eta (\partial_\mu g_{\eta\nu})
$$

Where $\delta^\mu_\eta$ is the *Kronecker delta*, does this become:-

$$
\partial_\eta g_{\mu\nu}
$$

Or can I just switch one of the indicies and get this:-

$$
\partial_\mu g_{\mu\nu}
$$

I'm guessing they both can't be correct because in the first all indexes are free and the second $\mu$ is a dummy index.

Comment: If you're using Einstein notation, then you are summing over $\mu$, so you get $\partial_\eta g_{\eta\nu}$. Note that you wrote $\partial_\eta g_{\mu\nu}$, but I can't see why you turned $g_{\eta\nu}$ into $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Ok, but are we not also summing over $\eta$? Why doesn't $\delta^\mu_\eta g_{\eta\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: You're not; in Einstein summation, you sum over indices that are repeated in the sense that they appear both as an upper index and as a lower index. Hence, in your expression, you sum over $\mu$, which appears as an upper index in $\delta_\eta^\mu$ and as a lower index in $\partial_\mu g_{\eta\nu}$, but not over $\eta$, which only appears as a lower index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the Kronecker delta is sometimes treated like an index substitution symbol, it actually defined as
$$
\delta_j^k = \begin{cases}
1, & j=k\\
0, & j\neq k
\end{cases}
$$
Now consider what happens when summing over one of those indices
$$
\sum_\mu \delta^\mu_\eta (\partial_\mu g_{\eta\nu})=\partial_\eta g_{\eta\nu}
$$
since this is the only non-zero summand. If we sum over the other index, then
$$
\sum_\eta\sum_\mu \delta^\mu_\eta (\partial_\mu g_{\eta\nu})=\sum_\eta \partial_\eta g_{\eta\nu}=\partial_1 g_{1\nu}+\partial_2 g_{2\nu}+\dotsb
$$
which is the same result you would get for summing over $\eta$ and then over $\mu$. Observe that in both cases this is different from $\partial_\eta g_{\mu\nu}$.

Finally, as I alluded to in my comment and as Branimir Ćaćić made explicit, in [Einstein notation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Einstein_rule) you sum only over those indices that appear both as an upper and a lower index. The other indices are considered constant throughout the summation.